# How can you view an email for the contact on an opportunity ? (salesforce classic)

Tags: opportunity, account, contact

I would like to see the email associated with the account when I search opportunities - is this possible? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can create formula field of text type on opportunity object. i.e.

```
Account.Email__c
```

Add this field in Search Layout.
And email will show on opportunity.

Comment: OH this is great! Thanks - Where do I do that? I am super new to salesforce...

Comment: you should check this one:
https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/modules/point_click_business_logic/units/formula_fields